# Remove the black line from the bottom and right side of Firefox select boxes

Tags: html, css, firefox

This may seem to be a stupid question but is there a way to remove the black line on the bottom and right sides from the drop down of a select box in Firefox?

For example:
http://postimg.org/image/6sqgo7xul/

Here is a basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FtVGg/33/

```
<div class="styled-select">
<select id="select">
<option value="0">Option one</option>
<option value="1">Another option</option>
<option value="2">Select this</option>
<option value="3">Something good</option>
<option value="4">Something bad</option>
```

Please open in Firefox to see black lower right corner lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you cant style the drop down box itself, just the input field. The box is rendered by the operating system so the only way to have control over the select is to use a plugin.

I would recommend the use of Chosen.js to have it look the same in all browsers.

Documentation:

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: If it rendered by the operating system then why does it look differently in other browsers? Thanks